# how to create key value RDD out of kafka topic data

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I am reading data from kafka topic in spark streaming job. I need to create key value RDD out of data.

```
val messages = KafkaUtils.createStream(streamingContext, "localhost:2181","abc",topics, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
messages.print()

  create key value RDD out of CustomerId and Tokens
  val xactionByCustomer = messages.map(_._2).map {
    transaction =>
      val key = transaction.customerId
      var tokens = transaction.tokens
      (key, tokens)
  }
```

Error ::

```
[error] /home/ec2-user/alok/marseille/src/main/scala/com/jcalc/feed/MarkovPredictor.scala:115: value customerId is not a member of String
[error]       val key = transaction.customerId
[error]                             ^
[error] /home/ec2-user/alok/marseille/src/main/scala/com/jcalc/feed/MarkovPredictor.scala:116: value tokens is not a member of String
[error]       var tokens = transaction.tokens
[error]                                ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

sample data ::

```
(null,W3Q6TF3CCI,X84N230CIH,NNN)
(null,O8IV7KEXT0,G1D590G05V,NNS)
(null,LBQKYNE081,MYU0O7JC5H,NHN)
(null,SRB4P501SW,E0FTI4RN7X,LHL)
(null,HELRFMAXVS,W6F704TN21,LHN)
(null,FS4PLQLI63,TK1O9YHS15,NNN)
(null,KI70UDVJLC,4ANBDAW7SU,LNN)
(null,IP6IVPGCWQ,MD93GGGBKA,NNN)
(null,976N9RPXSP,JKU0SV7UMH,LNL)
(null,J4V3AB1YVT,J9WXC1BRAY,LHN)
```

I am interested in 2nd & 4th value only for pair RDD.
Any Help ?

Answer (score 0):

Your data looks like tuple: `(String, String, String, String)` and since you're interested in 2dn & 4th value mapping:

```
val xactionByCustomer = messages.map(row => (row._2, row._4))
```

should be enough.

Comment: [error] /home/ec2-user/alok/sample/KafkaWordCount.scala:37: value _2 is not a member of String
[error]     val xactionByCustomer = messages.map(row => (row._2, row._4))
[error]                                                      ^
[error] /home/ec2-user/alok/sample/KafkaWordCount.scala:37: value _4 is not a member of String
[error]     val xactionByCustomer = messages.map(row => (row._2, row._4))
[error]                                                              ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed

Comment: That's strange, because `messages.map(_._2)` in your code succeeded and produced the String. Could you please paste the entire code with an update suggested by me?

Comment: I am trying to implement 1 POC from Github , In the link metioned below line no 105 is throwing error while submitting spark streaming job .      https://github.com/bhomass/marseille/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/jcalc/feed/MarkovPredictor.scala

Comment: I am getting below error while running the code :: is it spark config issue or  code related issue ? Could You please help                                                                   ERROR StreamingListenerBus: StreamingListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event StreamingListenerBatchCompleted(BatchInfo(1490260720000 ms,Map(0 -> StreamInputInfo(0,0,Map())),1490260720024,Some(1490260720030),Some(1490260720508),Map(0 -> OutputOperationInfo(1490260720000 ms,0,print at MarkovPredictor.scala:109,org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.print(DStream.scala:757)